# Python - каким способом лучше реализовать автоматическую установку ПО?

Tags: python, windows, click

Нужно написать код, который будет устанавливать ПО самостоятельно. Тут в голову приходит несколько идей:

1. делать клик по координатам (самый простой способ для меня, но имею большие сомнения по поводу других разрешений)
2. делать клик по отслеживанию изображения (условно дать изображение того, что нужно найти на экране. Нашел - нажал, ждешь пока не появится следующий этап и снова нажал) По нужному изображению так же можно легче по моему мнению отследить результат - установка успешна или нет. Хотя в установщике можно открыть Журнал и сделать вывод последних строк из txt с итогом установки, что тоже имеет место быть.

Какой из этих вариантов будет профитнее? И какую(ой) библиотеку/способ реализации нужен на 2ом варианте? Пытался найти самостоятельно - но увы и ах. Скорее всего проблема в неверном запросе...

Надеюсь достаточно ясно описал желаемое, однако заранее извиняюсь, тк я сейчас на этапе изучения языка, а эта задача - мой проект, который я должен реализовать.

Comment: 3. использовать инсталлятор, не требующий взаимодействия со средствами ввода.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin да, так точно будет проще проверить установку. Однако я упустил один из основных моментов в своём вопросе - цель. Хотелось бы не просто проверил установку, а автоматизировать пользовательский сценарий, объединив тест установки и UI

Comment: Установщик свой или чужой? Если свой, то по идее где-то среди инструментов для разработки должен быть какой-нибудь инструмент для тестирования интерфейсов, не требующий возни с изображениями